# Bulletproof background image not showing proper in Outlook - Email

Tags: html, email, outlook, background

I am currently trying to get background images to work in outlook to be able to create more creative e-mails. I have added the bulletproof background to the `td`. And it shows great everywhere else.

But not in outlook. I have tried changing to Points instead of px, with same result.

Does anyone have any good idea's how this can be solved?

[How it looks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Eg7AQ.png)

The code I have done is:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <!--[if !mso]><!-->
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <!--<![endif]-->
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no">
    <meta name="x-apple-disable-message-reformatting">
    <title></title>
    <style type="text/css">
        #outlook a {
            padding: 0;
        }
        
        .body {
            width: 100% !important;
            -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;
            -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
        }
        
        .ExternalClass {
            width: 100%;
        }
        
        .ExternalClass,
        .ExternalClass p,
        .ExternalClass span,
        .ExternalClass font,
        .ExternalClass td,
        .ExternalClass div {
            line-height: 100%;
            -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;
            -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;
            mso-line-height-rule: exactly;
        }
        
        img {
            border: 0;
            outline: none;
            text-decoration: none;
            -ms-interpolation-mode: bicubic;
        }
        
        a img {
            border: none;
        }
        
        p {
            margin: 1em 0;
        }
        
        table td {
            border-collapse: collapse;
            mso-table-lspace: 0;
            mso-table-rspace: 0;
        }
        /* hide unsubscribe from forwards*/
        
        blockquote .original-only,
        .WordSection1 .original-only {
            display: none !important;
        }
        
        @media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {
            body,
            table,
            td,
            p,
            a,
            li,
            blockquote {
                -webkit-text-size-adjust: none !important;
            }
            /* Prevent Webkit platforms from changing default text sizes */
            body {
                width: 100% !important;
                min-width: 100% !important;
            }
            /* Prevent iOS Mail from adding padding to the body */
            #bodyCell {
                padding: 10px !important;
            }
            #templateContainer {
                max-width: 600px !important;
                width: 100% !important;
            }
            h1 {
                font-size: 24px !important;
                line-height: 125% !important;
            }
            h2 {
                font-size: 20px !important;
                line-height: 125% !important;
            }
            h3 {
                font-size: 18px !important;
                line-height: 125% !important;
            }
            h4 {
                font-size: 16px !important;
                line-height: 125% !important;
            }
            #templatePreheader {
                display: none !important;
            }
            /* Hide the template preheader to save space */
            #logoImage {
                height: auto !important;
                max-width: 150px !important;
                width: 100% !important;
            }
            .headerContent {
                font-size: 20px !important;
                line-height: 125% !important;
            }
            #bodyImage {
                height: auto !important;
                max-width: 560px !important;
                width: 100% !important;
            }
            .bodyContent {
                font-size: 18px !important;
                line-height: 125% !important;
            }
            .templateColumnContainer {
                display: block !important;
                width: 100% !important;
            }
            .bannerImage {
                height: auto !important;
                max-width: 460px !important;
                width: 100% !important;
            }
            .imageContent,
            .container {
                padding-left: 0px!important;
                padding-right: 0px!important;
            }
            .footerContent {
                font-size: 12px !important;
                line-height: 115% !important;
            }
        }
    </style>

    <body bgcolor="#191919" style="-webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%; -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%; height: 100% !important; width: 100% !important; background-color: #191919; margin: 0; padding: 0;">
        <table align="center" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" id="bodyTable" style="-ms-text-size-adjust: 100%; -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%; background-color: #191919; border-collapse: collapse !important; height: 100% !important; margin: 0; mso-table-lspace: 0pt; mso-table-rspace: 0pt; padding: 0; width: 100% !important"
            width="100%">
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td align="center" id="bodyCell" style="-webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%; -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%; mso-table-lspace: 0pt; mso-table-rspace: 0pt; height: 100% !important; width: 100% !important;margin: 0; padding: 0 0 20px 0;" valign="top">
                        <!-- BEGIN TEMPLATE // -->
                        <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" id="templateContainer" style="-webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%; -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%; mso-table-lspace: 0pt; mso-table-rspace: 0pt; border-collapse: collapse !important; width: 624px;">
                            <tbody>
                                <tr>
                                    <td align="center" style="-webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%; -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%; mso-table-lspace: 0pt; mso-table-rspace: 0pt;" valign="top">
                                        <!-- BEGIN PREHEADER // -->
                                        <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" id="templatePreheader" style="-ms-text-size-adjust: 100%; -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%; background-color: #000000; border-collapse: collapse !important; mso-table-lspace: 0pt; mso-table-rspace: 0pt"
                                            width="100%">
                                            <tbody>
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td align="center" class="preheaderContent" pardot-region="preheader_content00" style="-webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%; -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%; mso-table-lspace: 0pt; mso-table-rspace: 0pt; color: #ffffff; font-family: Helvetica; font-size: 10px; line-height: 12px; text-align: center; letter-spacing:2; padding: 15px 20px;"
                                                        valign="top">OFFICIAL COMMUNICATION</td>
                                                </tr>
                                            </tbody>
                                        </table>
                                        <!-- // END PREHEADER -->

                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td align="center" style="-webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%; -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%; mso-table-lspace: 0pt; mso-table-rspace: 0pt;" valign="top">
                                        <!-- BEGIN HEADER // -->
                                        <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" id="templateHeader" style="-ms-text-size-adjust: 100%; -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%; background-color: #191919; border-collapse: collapse !important; mso-table-lspace: 0pt; mso-table-rspace: 0pt" width="100%">
                                            <tbody>
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td align="center" class="headerContent" height="140" style="-webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%; -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%; mso-table-lspace: 0pt; mso-table-rspace: 0pt;" valign="middle">
                                                        <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" id="templateHeader" style="-ms-text-size-adjust: 100%; -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%; background-color: #191919; border-collapse: collapse !important; mso-table-lspace: 0pt; mso-table-rspace: 0pt" width="100%">
                                                            <tbody>
                                                                <tr>
                                                                    <td align="left" style="padding-left: 30px;"><img alt="" height="50" id="logoImage" src="https://promo.mantracgroup.com/l/617741/2019-09-23/ftgc4/617741/66681/Logo_Mantrac.png" style="-ms-interpolation-mode: bicubic; height: auto; outline: none; text-decoration: none; max-width: 200px; border: 0;"
                                                                            width="200"></td>
                                                                    <td align="right" pardot-region="phone_content00" style="padding-top:12px;padding-right:30px;color: #FEC70B !important; display: block; font-family: Helvetica,sans-serif; font-size:24px; font-style: normal;text-transform:uppercase; font-weight: bold; letter-spacing: normal;margin: 0; text-align: right">
                                                                        <font color="#FEC70B" face="Helvetica,sans-serif">000-0000-0000</font>
                                                                    </td>
                                                                </tr>
                                                            </tbody>
                                                        </table>
                                                    </td>
                                                </tr>
                                            </tbody>
                                        </table>
                                        <!-- // END HEADER -->
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td background="https://promo.mantracgroup.com/l/617741/2020-03-23/th6sg/617741/89519/CRC_ghana_bg_email.png" bgcolor="#2c363a" width="624px" height="786" valign="top">
                                        <!--[if gte mso 9]>
                                        <v:rect xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" fill="true" stroke="false" style="mso-width-percent:100;width:624px;height:786px;">
                                          <v:fill type="tile" src="https://promo.mantracgroup.com/l/617741/2020-03-23/th6sg/617741/89519/CRC_ghana_bg_email.png"color="#2c363a"/>
                                          <v:textbox inset="0,0,0,0">
                                        <![endif]-->
                                        <div>
                                            <table width="100%" border="0" celllspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                                                <tbody>
                                                    <tr>
                                                        <td align="left" style="color: #FEC70B !important; margin-left:-30px!important; display: block; font-family: Helvetica,sans-serif; font-size: 38px; font-style: normal;text-transform:uppercase; font-weight: bold; letter-spacing: normal; line-height: 43px; text-align:left!important; margin: 0; margin-top:15px; text-align: center;padding-bottom:25px;padding-left:10%;padding-right:10%;"><span style="color:#FFFFFF;"><font face="Helvetica,sans-serif;display:block;">WONDER WHERE YOUR EQUIPMENT COMES BACK TO LIFE?</font></span></td>

                                                    </tr>
                                                    <tr>
                                                        <td>
                                                            <p style="text-align:left;margin:0; padding-left:10%;">
                                                                <a href="#"><img height="45" src="https://promo.mantracgroup.com/l/617741/2019-10-08/glkpx/617741/68593/btn_sample.png" width="168"></a>
                                                            </p>
                                                        </td>
                                                    </tr>
                                                </tbody>
                                            </table>



                                        </div>
                                        <!--[if gte mso 9]>
                                          </v:textbox>
                                        </v:rect>
                                        <![endif]-->
                                    </td>
                                    <!--begin content -->
                                </tr>
                            </tbody>
                        </table>

                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
        <!-- End content -->
        <!-- BEGIN FOOTER -->
        <table bgcolor="#000000" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" id="templateFooter" style="-ms-text-size-adjust: 100%; -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;mso-table-lspace: 0pt; mso-table-rspace: 0pt;background-color:#000000;" width="100%">
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td align="center" style="padding-top: 30px;"><img src="https://promo.mantracgroup.com/l/617741/2019-09-23/ftgc4/617741/66681/Logo_Mantrac.png" style="-ms-interpolation-mode: bicubic; height: auto; outline: none; text-decoration: none; max-width: 84px; border: 0;" width="84"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td align="center" class="footerContent" pardot-region="footer_content01" style="-webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%; -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%; mso-table-lspace: 0pt; mso-table-rspace: 0pt; color: #D8D8D8; font-family: Helvetica; font-size: 10px; line-height: 15px; text-align: center; padding: 20px 30px 10px 30px;"
                        valign="top">© {{Current_Year}} Mantrac Group. All rights reserved.</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td align="center" class="footerContent original-only" pardot-region="footer_content02" style="-webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%; -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%; mso-table-lspace: 0pt; mso-table-rspace: 0pt; color: #D8D8D8; font-family: Helvetica; font-size: 10px; line-height: 15px; text-align: center; padding: 0 30px 20px;"
                        valign="top">You’re receiving this email because you’ve agreed to receive notifications from Mantrac Group. If you’d prefer not to receive updates, you can <a href="{{EmailPreferenceCenter}}" style="-webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%; -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%; color: #D8D8D8; font-weight: normal; text-decoration: underline;">manage&nbsp;your&nbsp;preferences</a>                        or <a href="{{Unsubscribe}}" style="-webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%; -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%; color: #D8D8D8; font-weight: normal; text-decoration: underline;">unsubscribe&nbsp;from&nbsp;all</a>.</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>

        <!-- END FOOTER -->
    </body>


</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think `mso-width-percent:100;` should be `mso-width-percent:1000;`

Edit : `mso-width-percent` value is getting divided by 10 :

> It might look confusing at first, but mso-width-percent is actually quite simple. The number you need to pass to it is ten times the percentage you'd like. This means that mso-width-percent: 1000; is actually 100%, or full page width

Source : https://www.emailonacid.com/blog/article/email-development/emailology_vector_markup_language_and_backgrounds/

Comment: A good answer will always include an explanation why this would solve the issue, so that the OP and any future readers can learn from it.

Comment: Sorry / done ;)